# Intuition about axiomatic description of gluing

Tags: homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I am currently reading  "Methods of homological algebra" by S. I. Gelfand and Yu. I. Manin.

I was wondering if someone could explain the intuition about why $X(id) = id$ and $X(f \circ g) = X(f) \circ X(g)$ imply that to different elements of $X_n(f)$ correspond different simplices and face of a face is a face.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "Methods of homological algebra" by S. I. Gelfand and Yu. I. Manin.

This definition amounts to the following: consider the category $\Delta_+$ whose objects are
$$[0], [1], [2], [3], \ldots$$
and morphisms $f\colon [m] \to [n]$ are **strictly increasing** maps
$$\{ 0 < 1 < \cdots < m \} \to \{ 0 < 1 < \cdots < n \}.$$
Then what they call "gluing datum" is a contravariant functor
$$\tag{*} X\colon \Delta_+^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{Set}.$$
Such a thing is better known as a **[semi-simplicial set](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-simplicial+set)**. If you consider the bigger category $\Delta \supset \Delta_+$ where the morphisms are **nondecreasing** maps, then a functor
$$X\colon \Delta^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{Set}$$
is called a **simplicial set**.

Specifying (*) is equivalent to specifying

- a family of sets
  $$X_{(0)}, ~ X_{(1)}, ~ X_{(2)}, ~ X_{(3)}, ~ \ldots$$

and

- a map
  $$X(f)\colon X_{(n)} \to X_{(m)}$$
  for each increasing map $f\colon [m] \to [n]$.

And all this should be functorial, i.e.
$$X (id) = id, \quad X (g\circ f) = X (f)\circ X (g).$$
The elements of $X_{(n)}$ are called **$n$-simplices** (this is a standard terminology), and Gelfand and Manin call a **face** any map $X (f)\colon X_{(n)} \to X_{(m)}$, which intuitively, describes how simplices of dimension $m$ and $n$ are identified/glued.

Now for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is only one morphism $[n] \to [n]$, the identity map $id$, and requiring that $X (id) = id$ intuitively means that in each dimension $n$, the $n$-simplices $X_{(n)}$ are not being identified between themselves.

The condition $X (g\circ f) = X (f)\circ X (g)$ is some kind of transitivity: if you have morphisms $f\colon [\ell] \to [m]$ and $g\colon [m] \to [n]$, then gluing simplices in dimension $n$ and $\ell$ via $X (g\circ f)\colon X_{(n)} \to X_{(\ell)}$ should correspond to gluing via $X (g)\colon X_{(n)}\to X_{(m)}$ followed by gluing via $X (f)\colon X_{(m)} \to X_{(\ell)}$.

Comment: Okay that is perfect you answered my questions and more. Thanks.